# Redirect to another component after submit in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React. I would like to redirect to another page (another component) called MainModule from the login form after clicking the submit button.

This is my Login Form=>

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Button,FormGroup,FormControl,FormLabel,Form} from "react-bootstrap";


class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            email:"",
            password:""
        };
    }

    handelChange = event =>{
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]:event.target.value  
        },()=>{

        });       

    }

    handelSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.history.push('/MainModule');



    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handelSubmit}>

                    <FormGroup controlId="email">
                        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl autoFocus type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handelChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup controlId="password">
                        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handelChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>

                    <Button type="submit">Login</Button>
                </Form>



            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

but the problem is after I clicking the submit button, `url` change to MainModule but MainMoudle form is not shown and just showing the current login form.I think this needs to defind the route for MainModule and I don't know how to do that. Please help.

Update

My MainModules =>

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Route, Link,Switch,BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import allowance from './components/master/allowance';


class MainModule extends React.Component {
    // constructor(props){
    //   super(props)
    // }




    render(){
      return(
          <div className="mainform">
               <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">            
                <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/MainModule">TMS</Link>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div className="navbar-nav">
                        <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to={'/allowance'}>Allowance</Link>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </nav>

                <div id="maincontent">                 
                    <Route path='/allowance' component={allowance} />             
                </div>     
          </div>        
      )
    }
  }

  export default MainModule;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you do have to define a route for your `MainModule` component.

In your **App.js** file, which is where I'm assuming you have set up your Routes:

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Login from "/yourcomponentfolder/Login"
import MainModule from "/yourcomponentfolder/MainModule"

const App = () => {
   return(
      <BrowserRouter>
           <div>
               //Using exact tells react-router that you will only render this component if the URL matches exactly with the path definition.
               <Route path="/" component={Login} exact/>
               <Route path="/MainModule" component={MainModule}/>          
           </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
   )

}
```

It's pretty cut and dry, you use the `Route` component, give it a `path`, and a `component` to render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why show both login and MainModule components in MainModule url? I would like to show only MainModule.

Comment: @Jze Right, that tells me that your Login component is actually using a Route with a path of "/", if you dont want this to happen, update that Route to use the `exact` prop. I'll show you in my updated answer above.

Comment: After I changing like that Nav bar routing in MainModules not working anymore. Should I ask another question or discuss in chatroom?

Comment: @Jze post your MainModules component code. I can try to find what's wrong. The above code is the bare-minimum you need though to set up routing.

Comment: @Jze you need to change this line `<Route path='/allowance' component={allowance} />` you shouldn't be rendering the Route component like this. Just execute your component, replace it with: `<Allowance/>`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will have multiple nav link in feature and will show specify component when clicking each link (Like a normal nav bar working process). For that case, I can't do that  <Allowance/>, right?

Comment: @Jze. Right if you want each navlink to reroute to a different component you should make use of the Link component and define the right path for it. Additionally, you will have to establish a route for each component you want to render

Comment: could u please provide some example or link? If I set route in app.js and like "<Route path="./components/master/allowance" component={allowance}/>", It will go to allowance but my nav bar is missing and just show only allowance form (its make sense), for this case am I need to add nav to allowance form? But I think its not good practice. In the feature, I don't want to add this nav to each of components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195447/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-jze).